# Used note 4 clean spyware

Tags: samsung, factory-reset, malware

I purchased a used Note 4 off ebay and want to make completely sure there are no spy apps or malware on it. I know some spy apps can be installed into the system partition and survive a factory reset. I discovered an app called cerberus that could do this and could be used to spy on me and blackmail me. How do I completely clean my phone of all spy apps or malware and completely wipe everything including the system partition erasing everything.

Comment: By flashing a ROM and recovery image. And btw, Cerberus is a security app to help you find your device in case it's lost, it's not a spyware, and it doesn't blackmail you. Unless there's a second app going by the same name.

Comment: How do I flash a rom and recovery image? Cerberus can be used as spyware.

Comment: @Jamesredo, are you sure you understand what Cerberus does and what spyware is?

Answer (score 0):

Cerberus is an anti theft app. It can be used to maliciously spy on you making it spyware. I don't know who has used this phone or where it has been anything could be on it.